# Docker Compose Start Worker After Reboot?

Tags: laravel, docker, docker-compose

I use docker compose to manage docker image in web based using laravel. Here is my docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3"
services:
  api:
    image: nginx:latest
    ports:
      - "5556:80"
    volumes:
        - .:/usr/api/
        - ./site.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/site.conf
        - /usr/api/vendor
    links:
        - app
    restart: unless-stopped
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: php.dockerfile
    tty: true
    volumes:
        - .:/usr/api/
        - /usr/api/vendor
        - ./uploads.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/uploads.ini
    restart: unless-stopped
```

My configuration above automatically run docker when server reboot. My question is how to run worker job automatically when server reboot. Right now, i run worker manually using command docker-compose exec app php artisan queue:work. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use supervisor to automatically start/restart services. See the Laravel docs here:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queues#supervisor-configuration

I use supervisor to manage Horizon queue workers.

[Example config from the docs:](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/horizon#running-horizon)

```
[program:horizon]
process_name=%(program_name)s
command=php /home/forge/app.com/artisan horizon
autostart=true
autorestart=true
user=forge
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile=/home/forge/app.com/horizon.log
```

Alternatively, you can use systemd or a similar process manager by itself, if you're on Linux.

[Run supervisor on startup](http://supervisord.org/running.html#running-supervisord-automatically-on-startup)

[Manage Docker as non root user](https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/linux-postinstall/)

[pm2 is another popular process manager](https://github.com/Unitech/pm2)

Comment: so in supervisor config, i just call docker-compose exec app php artisan ?, currently i need sudo to execute docker-compose, how to handle password for su account?

Comment: First, you should create a docker group if it doesn't exist  and add your user to the group. I try not to use root (or sudo) with docker whenever possible.Second, you're correct in that you would add the command `docker-compose exec app php artisan ` to the config. You can run supervisor as root so the password won't be necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You need to integrate `php artisan queue:work` command in your entrypoint script.

Ref - https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/multi-service_container/

Comment: yes i have added in entrypoint conf in docker-compose.yml. But somehow, it the links with nginx is broken. The answer from @btl using supervisor solved the problem.